# How to map a VPN (tun0) network adapter on host Ubuntu to a VirtualBox guest Windows?

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have a Ubuntu 10.04 running Oracle VirtualBox 3.2.6 with a Windows XP guest.
I use a VPN that I would like to be accessed by the guest VM, on a ifconfig it shows as:

```
tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:5.192.10.99  P-t-P:5.192.10.99  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1362  Metric:1
          RX packets:14151 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:19860 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:4415271 (4.4 MB)  TX bytes:17949982 (17.9 MB)
```

Using NAT or Bridge adapters on the VM only gives me the non-vpn adapter.
How can I map the tun0 adapter to VirtualBox?

Comment: It did not work for me but it is clearly correct advance.
Setting sysctl.conf:
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
Then running 
sudo sysctl -p

Comment: Finally it is working, though it did not work when I loaded sysctl. Later I found it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Then running:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

(Should not be necessary but) I rebooted after that.

Answer (score 3):

I met the same problem, and googled around but found no answer.  at last I found my solution:

1. in windows, open the VPN connection using VPN GUI.
2. in VM configuration, add a new Network:  Internal network.
3. restart VM.

then I can access the resource in VM.